# Changing value of textbox on webpage via Powershell

Tags: powershell, html-table, textbox, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to connect to a webpage and edit the value of a text box via powershell.
Making a HttpWebRequest is fine but how would I go about locating the text box and changing its value?

Here is my web site code, I want to change the value of: td class="noBorder"

```
  <table class="runnerFormTable">
     <tr>
<th class="noBorder"><label for="description">Description:</label></th>
<td class="noBorder"><input type="text" name="description" id="description" size="" maxlength="256" value="From Deploy" class="textfield" style="margin:0; padding:0; width:35em;"></td>
     </tr>
      <input type="hidden" id="submit" name="submit" value="store"/>
   </table>
```

Comment: Are you going to post the data after you change the value of the textbox?

Comment: Yes, the change has to be saved

Comment: Is just posting the data you want sufficient, instead of trying to manipulate controls on the page?

Comment: I just want to change the value of a text box from one string to another and save the change